# converting heic image to png / jpeg with sharp node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, buffer, sharp, heic

When I want to convert png file like this

```
const file = await this.awsS3Service.getObject(fileEntity.awsS3Key);

const body = await this.awsS3Service.streamToBuffer(file.Body as Readable);

const outputBuffer = await sharp(body).toFormat('png').toBuffer();
```

i get file from aws and then convert file to buffer and then want to convert heic image to png or jpeg image. On this line  await sharp(body).toFormat('png').toBuffer(); I get error Stack: Error: source: bad seek to 1508850
heif: Unsupported feature: Unsupported codec (4.3000)

I tried also

```
const outputBuffer = await sharp(body).png().toBuffer();
```

, but this was working like one month ago